# Web AppBuilder for ARCGIS unknown error : [TypeError: must start with number, buffer, array or string]

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

I am trying to log in my arcgis web appbuilder version 2.5 but its getting failed by showing some error ([TypeError: must start with number, buffer, array or string]) in my terminal. see below image..

[image]

When I log in using arcgis web appbuilder  version 2.3. Its successful.

Comment: Have you made any changes to the Web Appbuilder files or is this a newly downloaded and unzipped version of the tool?

Comment: Ya newly downloaded and unzipped. Nothing I modified. It still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be an issue with your OS and Node.js version not jiving with the npm package versions that the proxy server is using (see `server/package.json`) - I would recommend opening an issue with [Esri Support](https://support.esri.com/en/) to try to get to the bottom of the specific issue.